# Merge array of hashes: value should be the average of merged values

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Issue: Merge array of hashes with the same value of specified key and find average for the other keys.

My solution seems to be ugly

data:

```
require 'pp'

arr = [{:red=>346.0,
  :unu=>10.0,
  :used=>20147.0,
  :acc_id=>550,
  :percent=>0.01},
 {:red=>0.0,
  :unu=>1.0,
  :used=>66.0,
  :acc_id=>550,
  :percent=>0.06},
 {:red=>120.0,
  :unu=>11.0,
  :used=>166.0,
  :acc_id=>550,
  :percent=>10.06},
 {:red=>1306.0,
  :unu=>1.0,
  :used=>13259.0,
  :acc_id=>9999,
  :percent=>0.0}]
```

In current example we should merge 3 hashes with ( :acc_id = 550 ) and result array should contain two hashes ( merged hash with :acc_id = 550 and untouched hash with :acc_id = 9999 )

algorithm:

```
data = []
arr.group_by{|h| h[:acc_id] }.map {|_, arr_of_hashes|
  sz = arr_of_hashes.size
  if sz > 1
    arr_of_hashes = arr_of_hashes.inject{|memo, el|
      memo.merge(el) {|k, old_v, new_v| old_v + new_v}
    }

    arr_of_hashes.map {|k, v| arr_of_hashes[k] = v / sz}
  end
  data << arr_of_hashes if arr_of_hashes.is_a? Hash
  data << arr_of_hashes[0] if arr_of_hashes.is_a? Array
}

pp data
```

Expected result:
Array of merged hashes

```
[{:red=>155.33333333333334,
  :unu=>7.333333333333333,
  :used=>6793.0,
  :acc_id=>550,
  :percent=>3.376666666666667},
 {:red=>1306.0,
  :unu=>1.0,
  :used=>13259.0,
  :acc_id=>9999,
  :percent=>0.0}]
```

...
...
...

Comment: When you give an example you should always show the desired result.

Comment: I assume you want the average value for each key, taken over all the hashes in `arr`. Is that correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland added expected result. I want to merge hashes with the same value of key ( :acc_id in current example ) and find average for all other keys

Comment: For your example what is the “specified key”?

Comment: @CarySwoveland :acc_id. Also added some explanation in description

Comment: If hash values are not guaranteed to be floats you may wish to tack `.to_f` onto the end of `sz = arr_of_hashes.size` or change `v/sz` to `v.fdiv(sz)`. Even if they are all floats, the mods I mentioned would future-proof your code, should hash values be permitted to be integers one day.

Answer (score 0):

I found one bug you perform `/` and `+` on `acc_id` Have refactored the code 
let's try this but I guess we still improve this.

```
data = []
arr.group_by{|h| h[:acc_id] }.map {|_, arr_of_hashes|
  sz = arr_of_hashes.size
  result = Hash.new(0)
  arr_of_hashes.map{ |hash| hash.map{ |k,v| result[k] += v/sz unless k == :acc_id } }
  result[:acc_id] = arr_of_hashes.first[:acc_id]
  data << result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you compute the averages as follows. I assume that, as in the example, all hashes have the same keys (though they need not necessarily appear in the same order).

**Code**

```
def doit(arr, key)
  keys = arr.first.keys
  arr.group_by { |g| g[key] }.
      map do |_,a| 
        averages = a.map { |h| h.values_at(*keys) }.
                     transpose.
                     map { |v| v.sum.fdiv(v.size) }
        keys.zip(averages).to_h
      end
end
```

**Example**

Notice that my array of hashes is somewhat different than that given in example in the question. Specifically, there are three (rather than two) groups of hashes for which the value of the key `:acc_id` has a common value.

```
arr = [{ red: 346.0,  unu: 10.0, used: 20147.0, acc_id: 550,  percent: 0.01 },
       { red: 0.0,    unu: 1.0,  used: 66.0,    acc_id: 550,  percent: 0.06 },
       { red: 120.0,  unu: 11.0, used: 166.0,   acc_id: 10,   percent: 10.06 },
       { red: 100.0,  unu: 19.0, used: 170.0,   acc_id: 10,   percent: 11.56 },
       { red: 1306.0, unu: 1.0,  used: 13259.0, acc_id: 9999, percent: 0.0 }]

doit(arr, :acc_id)
  #=> [{:red=>173.0, :unu=>5.5, :used=>10106.5, :acc_id=>550.0, :percent=>0.035},
  #    {:red=>110.0, :unu=>15.0, :used=>168.0, :acc_id=>10.0, :percent=>10.81},
  #    {:red=>1306.0, :unu=>1.0, :used=>13259.0, :acc_id=>9999.0, :percent=>0.0}]
```

**Explanation**

See [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) (the latter having made its debut in v2.4).

The steps are as follows.

```
key = :acc_id
keys = arr.first.keys
  #=> [:red, :unu, :used, :acc_id, :percent]
b = arr.group_by { |g| g[key] }
  #=> { 550=>[{:red=>346.0, :unu=>10.0, :used=>20147.0, :acc_id=>550, :percent=>0.01},
  #           {:red=>0.0, :unu=>1.0, :used=>66.0, :acc_id=>550, :percent=>0.06}],
  #      10=>[{:red=>120.0, :unu=>11.0, :used=>166.0, :acc_id=>10, :percent=>10.06},
  #           {:red=>100.0, :unu=>19.0, :used=>170.0, :acc_id=>10, :percent=>11.56}],
  #    9999=>[{:red=>1306.0, :unu=>1.0, :used=>13259.0, :acc_id=>9999, :percent=>0.0}]}
b.map do |_,a| 
  averages = a.map { |h| h.values_at(*keys) }.
               transpose.
               map { |v| v.sum.fdiv(v.size) }
  keys.zip(averages).to_h
end 
  #=> <the array of hashes shown above>
```

Comment: Seems like rails solution, because of 'sum' method. But i replaced it with inject(0, :+) and it doesn't work like expected

Comment: Nice-looking solution, but it's x3 slower than the original solution. File with measures:  [link](https://pastebin.com/cQ71Zbvj)

Comment: You found that "it's x3 times slower" when tested with the example array of hashes. It may be faster or slower with other data. Note also that my code differs from yours in two respects: 1. I do not assume anything about the ordering of hash keys (by using `Hash#values_at`). Even if (for Ruby v1.9+) keys have the same order in all hashes, your code may produce erroneous results when run with earlier Ruby versions, in which there was no concept of key ordering. 2. Once averages have been computed I construct a hash to relate them to the keys (`keys.zip(averages).to_h`).